# How to install npm in folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

[this is folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycAoC.png)
I have a npm installed folder, when i copy that folder and run on desktop its not working. I use npm run ds to run server and view the website.

my desktop doesnot have npm. What is the procedure to install npm folder and run the react.js website?

Answer (score 1):

Setup React.js Environment Using Npm simple hello world

1.mkdir foldername

2.cd foldernmae

3.npm init

Installing and Configuring Webpack
npm i webpack -S

touch webpack.config.js

Update the config file as follows

```
 var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

then create the index,js file and in the ./src/client/app , add the following code 
console.log('Hello World!');

Now in the terminal run the following command

./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d

Answer (score 0):

goto Desktop using terminal/cmd prompt and execute `npm install`

Comment: i run npm install,  then i went to that folder and run npm init then i tried running npm run ds, but i got error "Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base .
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs peak-react"

Comment: did you created the folder using `npm init` or creating a `package.json` file then `npm install`? please update the folder structure.

Comment: i have added folder structure. I have package.json

Answer (score 0):

> "my desktop doesnot have npm"

Probably you do not have [**Node.js**](https://nodejs.org/en/) either.

Well, to start with, install Node.js first. You will need Node.js to run JavaScript on your desktop.

**Windows:**

Download `.msi` installer from here https://nodejs.org/en/download/

**Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

For any other OS, the steps are explained here https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

If you follow the above procedures, [**npm** (Node Package Manager)](https://www.npmjs.com/)  is also automatically installed on your system.

Now if you run `node -v` you will see the installed Node.js version.

Similarly `npm -v` shows your current `npm` version.

After this, you can go to your project folder and run `npm install`.

`npm install` inside a folder will scan through `package.json` and install all dependencies locally.

Refer your `package.json` "scripts",

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base"
     ...
   }
```

If you have something like this, then run `npm run start` to start your App.

Comment: @downvoter, Was I  missing the context? I still didn't get it, please enlighten me! :)